# Erase elements from multimap, based on key values?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

How would I erase all elements from an *std::multimap* who have a key less than or equal to *20*?

I know how to erase, I don't know how to pass in the condition *"key less than 20"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next code should work:

```
std::multimap<int, int> M;
// initialize M here
auto it = M.upper_bound(20);
M.erase(M.begin(), it);
```

Just use [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) and then [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multimap<int, int> mp;

    mp.insert(make_pair(10, 20));
    mp.insert(make_pair(11, 22));
    mp.insert(make_pair(12, 24));
    mp.insert(make_pair(12, 25));
    mp.insert(make_pair(13, 26));
    mp.insert(make_pair(24, 27));
    mp.insert(make_pair(25, 29));
    mp.insert(make_pair(26, 30));

    for(auto& elem : mp)
        cout<<"  first = "<<elem.first<<"  second = "<<elem.second<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    for(auto pos = mp.begin(); pos!=mp.end();)
    {
        if(pos->first <= 20)
            mp.erase(pos++);
        else
            ++pos;
    }

    for(auto& elem : mp)
        cout<<"  first = "<<elem.first<<"  second = "<<elem.second<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```